# Reading a textfile line by line in C

Tags: c, file, scanf, fgets

I need to be able to get data from a text file, which is presented in the following format:

> Starting Cash: 1500
>   Turn Limit (-1 for no turn limit): 10
>   Number of Players Left To End Game: 1
>   Property Set Multiplier: 2
>   Number of Houses Before Hotels: 4
>   Must Build Houses Evenly: Yes
>   Put Money In Free Parking: No
>   Auction Properties: No
>   Salary Multiplier For Landing On Go: 1

To clarify, I need the data presented after the colon. I'm not really sure how to approach this. I was reading other questions and they all said to use `fgets`, but I don't know how long each line will be and we can't statically allocate C strings, so where would I store the line pointed to by `fgets`? Also, is it possible to do this using `fscanf` (we have learned how to do `fscanf` but not learned `fgets`)? My idea when approaching this was to get each line, and then scan each line with sscanf (I think that would work) using the string literals that I don't need:

```
sscanf(str, "Starting Cash: %d", &startingCash);
```

Would this work?

Comment: You can use `strchr` to locate the position of the colon in the line. Or you can use `strtok` to parse the line

Comment: *"we can't statically allocate C strings"*. The simple way is to define a local array big enough to hold the longest input you expect. Use `fgets` and restrict the input length, as it requires.

Comment: *"I need the data presented after the colon."* Is there any guarantee that the data is presented in the same sequence?

Comment: If not you will need to use `strstr()` to find a decisive substring inside your line or a custom regexp matcher and then use `atoi()` for numbers or `strcmp()` for "Yes" and "No" statements according to what you think it is.

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask] and [MCVE].  You obviously haven't worked this problem hard enough to have sufficient code to have run into a real problem yet.  I'd be willing to bet you can find other SO users who have worked exactly the same assignment.  Some of them probably got answers.  Lookup `malloc()` and `free()` or simply create an array on the stack for your string buffer.  Yes, `sscanf()` is a good choice for finding prefixes in strings and converting  tokens to whatever type you need.  With any luck, nobody here will post a solution to your homework assignment.

Comment: Or simply use *character oriented input* like `fgetc` and check for `':'` and then `'\n'` (the stuff in between, minus any leading or trailing whitespace, is what you want)

Comment: @ft_error [`atoi` is harmful and shouldn't be used](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17710018/995714)

Answer (score 1):

After opening the file with `fopen()`, you could do

```
float cash;
int turnlimit, plyrno, mult, house;
fscanf(fin, "%*[^:]: %f", &cash);
fscanf(fin, "%*[^:]: %d", &turnlimit);
fscanf(fin, "%*[^:]: %d", &plyrno);
```

where `fin` is the `FILE` pointer.

`%[^:]` would scan till, but not including, a `:` is encountered and the `*` is for assignment suppression; meaning the value for it would be read but not assigned anywhere.

After reading till the point before the `:`, the `:` itself followed by a space must be read. So a `:` must be there in the format string followed by a space.

See [What is the purpose of using the [^ notation in scanf?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/766516/5375464) .